# How should I interpret the latter part of this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> You agree that all information you provide to us is true, accurate and
>   complete, **and you will** maintain and update such information regularly. (https://americanmary.com/terms/)

The latter part of this sentence is not clear. Does this mean:

> You agree that all information you provide to us is true, accurate and
>   complete. **And you agree that you will** maintain and update such
>   information regularly.

or

> You agree that all information you provide to us is true, accurate and
>   complete. **And you will** maintain and update such information
>   regularly.

Comment: Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+true+accurate+and+complete%2Cis+true+and+complete%2Cis+accurate+and+complete&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20true%20and%20complete%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20accurate%20and%20complete%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cis%20true%20and%20complete%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20accurate%20and%20complete%3B%2Cc0), the most common form today is ***true and complete***, followed by ***accurate and complete***. It's awkwardly tautological to specify ***both*** the first two (synonymous) adjectives.

Comment: (Whether or not to "delete" repeated elements as per your examples is entirely a stylistic choice. And *semantically*, I don't think it makes sense to speculate on whether *not* explicitly repeating ***you agree*** could be interpreted as implying that aspect of the final clause was never intended in the first place.)

Comment: Redundancy like this draws from old civil law where "true" meant not a lie, "accurate" meant objectively correct, and "complete" meant without omission.  So, all three elements were necessary.  Today, it is just a holdover from older times and a "just in case" for clever users wanting a loophole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a compound sentence, and "you agree" is being shared by both parts.

> You agree that all information you provide to us is true, accurate and complete,
>
> [You agree] you will maintain and update such information regularly.

Answer (score 0):

It is formally ambiguous, and in principle could mean either of those.

But in practice, your first meaning is either a prediction or a command, and neither of these seem to fit with the context, so it must be your second meaning.